# slug is getting replaced by name while updating

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a couple of methods in the model to generate a slug from the given name (input). It works fine while I create, but it takes "name" instead of hitting that method (for slug) while I update. The methods are :

```
public function thanas() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Thana', 'thana_id');
}

public function setSlugAttribute($name) {
    $this->attributes['slug'] = $this->getSlug($name);
}

public function getSlug($name) {
    $slug = Str::slug($name, '-');
    $count = Product::where('slug', 'LIKE', "%".$name."%")->count();
    $newCount = $count > 0 ? ++$count : '';
    return $newCount > 0 ? "$slug-$newCount" : $slug;
}
```

My controller :

```
$name = $request->name;

    if(!$validation->fails()) {
        $update = Product::where('id', $id)->update([
           'name'           => $request->name,
           'slug'           => $name,
           'order'          => $request->order,
           'status'         => $request->status
        ]);

        if($update) {
            return response()->json(200);
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json(['errors' => $validation->errors()],401);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple option available, since you didn't mention your framework version so mentioning the most generic & easist way to do that.

```
    $name = $request->name;

    if(!$validation->fails()) {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->setSlugAttribute($request->name);
        

        if($product->save()) {
            return response()->json(200);
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json(['errors' => $validation->errors()],401);
    }
```

There are a few others, you can try according to the Laravel version. Check the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: I am using version 9

Comment: Then you can use the mutators given in the doc.

Comment: I am actually using mutator, it works fine for create(), but not working for update()